# Online Source for Rackmount Server Shipping Box

Tags: rackmount, mailbox

I have three Dell rackmount servers (2 2U, 1 4U) that I need to ship from Las Vegas to New York. Old shipping boxes that came with the servers were discarded sometime ago. Where can I buy some that fit nicely and can be shipped by UPS or Fedex? I've tried UPS, Fedex, and Uhaul already.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh the joys of being a cardboard engineer.

Comment: Yes, packing is such a chore especially with these kind of equipment. I rather enjoy unpacking though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Uline.  They have a full range of shipping supplies including many specialty items for keyboards, laptops, etc.  Their target audience is companies who ship things on a regular basis. So, you may get stuck with a minimum quantity and have to buy more than you need.

- Styrofoam sheets

  http://www.uline.com/BL_874/Polystyrene-Sheets
- Foam Planks

  [www.uline.com/BL_868/Plank-Foam](http://www.uline.com/BL_868/Plank-Foam)
- Edge Protectors

  [www.uline.com/Product/Detail/S-6065/Protectors/4-x-4-x-48-Foam-Edge-Protectors](http://www.uline.com/Product/Detail/S-6065/Protectors/4-x-4-x-48-Foam-Edge-Protectors)
- Corner Protectors

  [www.uline.com/Product/Detail/S-6064/Protectors/3-5-8-x-3-x-2-Foam-Corner-Protectors](http://www.uline.com/Product/Detail/S-6064/Protectors/3-5-8-x-3-x-2-Foam-Corner-Protectors)
- Expanding Foam In Bags

  [www.uline.com/BL_7708/Instapak-Quickreg-Room-Temperature](http://www.uline.com/BL_7708/Instapak-Quickreg-Room-Temperature)

And they have more boxes than you can imagine.  This URL should get you started:

- [Heavy Duty Double-Wall Boxes](http://www.uline.com/BL_418/275-Lb-Test-Double-Wall-Boxes?keywords=275+Lb.+Test+Double+Wall+Boxes)

PS: Sorry that many of the above URL's aren't hyperlinks.  New users can only have one link per post.

Comment: Sounds just like what I was looking for. Thanks Tom!

Comment: Picked out this box here:

http://www.uline.com/Product/Detail/S-4683/Corrugated-Boxes-Heavy-Duty/41-x-28-3-4-x-25-1-2-Double-Wall-275-lb-Corrugated-Boxes

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a direct answer but when faced with a similar situation I simply used a whole lot of bubble-wrap and shoved it into a large very sturdy box that I obtained from a local moving company.

Comment: I do this when I am shipping servers also. Head to the back of your local department store and ask nicely for some decently sized boxes and you should be off and racing!

Comment: +1, bubble wrap and a refrigerator box from UHaul. Also, strongly consider having someone from the company drive them to the destination.

Comment: Don't have time to go out and ask the department store folk for boxes. Good idea though. Bubble-wrap... hmmmm...

Answer (score 0):

As @John Gardiniers says, lots of wrap and  a sturdy box is great.  Several shipping agencies in our area use a foam in place system and it works well and fully protects the hardware.  Not available everywhere but link might help find a local location [FoamInPlace](http://www.masterpkg.com/foam-in-place.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Call Dell Business or your Dell rep, I'm sure they can throw a few empty boxes your way.

Answer (score 0):

Reach out to Austin Foam Plastics, Inc. they provide the shipping boxes to dell and will sell direct.